# AutoHotKey Regular Expression

Tags: regex, autohotkey

I'm writing a script to ease subtitle (srt) generation.
I've got a hotkey to grab the timestamp from a player and paste it.
However the player (Express Scribe) unfortunately shows timestamps in this format: 00:00:00.00 and SRT uses 00:00:00,00.

I want to do two things.

1. Change the '.' to a ','
2. Store the timestamp as a var and then increase the last milliseconds by a little bit. ie. 00:00:00,00 becomes 00:00:00,50

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to do the increment in regex or which programming language? What have you tried so far?

Comment: It's an AutoHotKey script...
The regex is specifically to detect the timestamp format and increase it. 
AHK does actually have timeformat - so I might be able to skip the regex completely.

Comment: Ended up doing this:

`StringReplace, NewStr, string, ., :, All`
`StringSplit, TimeArray, NewStr, ":"`

Where string is the original time (00:00:00.5) 
Then splitting it, I can add to the last milliseconds in TimeArray

Comment: I doubt that the last part of the string are milliseconds, unless they can have 3 digits. The thing is 1000milliseconds are eqal to 1 second. So we would need 3 digits to display 000-999. It's more likely that it is centiseconds. 100centiseconds = 1 second so we can display 00-99 using 2 digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The really tricky thing about this is that a timestamp like
`05:59:59.60`
can't easily be incremented by 50.
The result should be
`06:00:00,10`
because a centisecond can't exceed 99 and a second can't exceed 59 (just like a minute can't).

So we need to use some annoying math here:

```
playerFormat := "01:10:50.70"

;extract hour, minute, second and centisecond using regex
RegExMatch(playerFormat,"O)(?P<hour>\d+):(?P<minute>\d+):(?P<second>\d+)\.(?P<centisecond>\d+)",matches)

;convert the strings to numbers by removing the leading zeros
hour := LTrim(matches.hour,"0")
minute := LTrim(matches.minute,"0")
second := LTrim(matches.second,"0")
centisecond := LTrim(matches.centisecond,"0")

;translate the total time into centiseconds
centiSecondsTotal := centisecond + second*100 + minute*100*60 + hour*100*60*60

;add 50 centiseconds (=0.5 seconds) to it
centiSecondsTotal += 50

;useing some math to translate the centisecond number that we just added the 50 to into hours, minutes, seconds and remaining centiseconds again
hour := Floor(centiSecondsTotal / (60*60*100))
centiSecondsTotal -= hour*60*60*100
minute := Floor(centiSecondsTotal/(60*100))
centiSecondsTotal -= minute*100*60
second := Floor(centiSecondsTotal/(100))
centiSecondsTotal -= second*100
centisecond := centiSecondsTotal

;add leading zeros for all numbers that only have 1 now
hour := StrLen(hour)=1 ? "0" hour : hour
minute := StrLen(minute)=1 ? "0" minute : minute
second := StrLen(second)=1 ? "0" second : second
centisecond := StrLen(centisecond)=1 ? "0" centisecond : centisecond

;create the new timestamp string
newFormat := hour ":" minute ":" second "," centisecond
MsgBox, %newFormat% ;Output is 01:10:51,20
```

Comment: That's fantastic. .
My fix before I read this was to just add 00 to the end of the centiseconds. And just increase by 1. And if it happens to be a 9 - make it an 8 instead before adding 1. What's a centisecond between friends ;-) But your solution is great and far more versatile.

Comment: A centisecond is a 100th of a second. Meaning 100 centiseconds = 1 second. Just like 100 centimeters are 1 meter.